# Rails "Template is missing" error, though it exists (3.2.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, templates, resources, routes

I just started using Rails and am not sure what I'm not doing correctly.

In routes.rb I have

```
resources :pages
```

In app/controllers/pages_controller.rb I have

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

I have a layout in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb and a template in app/views/home/pages/index.html.erb which I want rendered when I request "/pages". However, I get the error

> Template is missing
>
> Missing template pages/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en],
>   :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
>   * "/###/app/views"

I've been using stackoverflow for ages without posting, but so many different things seem to trigger this error that it's hard to find answers for my particular case. Also I'm a noob :3 Please help!

Comment: If your text editor is in the midst of writing to the file at the time you refresh, the file isn't available and it will cause an error like that. It happens.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You say you have `app/views/home/pages/index.html.erb` to represent the index view for your pages resource. I think the `home/` directory is not required.

In other words, your view file should be `app/views/pages/index.html.erb`.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this was a lack-of-sleep error :p I'd upvote you if I could.

Answer (score 5):

It's looking to find it in `app/views/pages/index` but you have it in `app/views/home/pages/index`. That slight difference makes it so that the Rails convention is lost.

If you must keep your new directory hierarchy, do this on your controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :partial => "home/pages/index"
  end
end
```

But, by default, if you have a resource, like `:pages`, it will automatically look in `app/views/pages`.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information! I personally don't need to do this, but someone else might.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I resolved it by just changing the folder name from car to cars. I had to change the folder name from singular to plural.